# Paste value into column based off value in another column

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of people's names and the country they're from.

For each country, I have a different message.
For example, if the value in the **Country** column is **Germany**, then the line "Hallo, guten tag" is pasted into the **Greetings** column.
If the country is **Spain**, then "Hola" is inserted into the **Greetings** column.

The macro needs to detect which country they're from, then paste the appropriate greeting in the **Greetings** column.

Comment: You're not being specific enough. Where is this data read from and where should it be written to (columns, worksheets)? Do you have any code or formula you have tried? Do you have any sample data or screenshots? Please add any additional information to your post.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like it could be solved by a simple VLOOKUP formula:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,LookUp!$A:$B,2,FALSE),"")
```

where A2 is a value in a country column

and A:B is a table consisting of two columns, country and greeting, on a separate tab named, in my case, as LookUp

the function IFERROR delivers an empty cell if the country in column A doesn't exist in the table on the LookUp tab

Here are the images of the LookUp table [image: table] and and the formula [image: formula].

Comment: your answer is unclear, although the formula works. You can expand the data sample, add images of the spreadsheets, which would greatly improve the appearance and make it much easier to understand. You can find more information on writing good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer (anyway I upvoted it)